# Why isn't an EventEmitter instance needed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, ecmascript-6

Below is a working example of EventEmitters.

I would have expected something like this

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Logger extends EventEmitter {
  emitter = New EventEmitter();                 // <----

  log(msg) {
    console.log(msg);

    emitter.emit('msgLogger', {id: 1, val: 2}); // <---
  };
};
```

In the correct implementation, I don't understand how the `EventEmitter` instance is shared, as I don't see `New EventEmitter()` anywhere.

Just because a class requires a module, doesn't make it an instance, right?

**app.js**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const Logger = require('./Logger');
const logger = new Logger();

logger.on('msgLogger', (arg) => {
  console.log('Listener called', arg);
});

logger.log('Triggered');
```

**Logger.js**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Logger extends EventEmitter {
  log(msg) {
    console.log(msg);

    this.emit('msgLogger', {id: 1, val: 2});
  };
};

module.exports = Logger;
```

Comment: The `Logger` is extends the `EventEmitter` so by instantiating the subclass (`Logger`) you're invoking the parent's constructor [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJ1JGBvAUNfwA9gHYQAuq8wZhqAFAJTS76vRGmEjIB0IhAczoByAO4BLECGgAjZNHHEAboQDWyACbQSC0mTDEy4sEZLCGefAF8cNnBihx4MhzGQAPMsmIaYCFOjgjlh2xMiiTi5BEIxAA)

Comment: So it creates an "invisible" instance of EventEmitter when I `New Logger()`? Is there a way I can see the "invisible" instance in a debugger?

Comment: Actually the Logger instance is also an instance of EventEmitter, it will have all of its properties and methods. And yes, you can inspect it with the debugger

Comment: Now it make more sense =) Thanks =)